# Quotes in regex syntax

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping and regex syntax.
I'm trying to find all matches for videoIds from a YouTube search html file. I'm not able to do it with BeautifulSoup's parse, since they were recently moved to a JS script. So I'm trying with regex.

They appear in the JS script as something like: `"videoId":"jNQXAC9IVRw"`

Note the ID is always 11 characters long.

So far, I'm trying:

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
pattern = re.compile('<quote>(\w{11})<quote>')
    
matches = re.findall(pattern, html)
for i in range(3):
    print(matches[i])
```

But it won't find anything.
My desire is to have a list of IDs, like:

```
lYtFMmByfJk
d2RlyAz6VQ
utTAphB1y4Y
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think `<quote>` will be found in JavaScript. Try using a more unique pattern like `pattern = re.compile('videoId":"(.+?)"')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change < quote > to ", it should work:

```
import re

html = '"videoId":"jNQXAC9IVRw","videoId":"jNQXACffRwl","videoId":"jNQXAC9ffsw"'
pattern = re.compile('videoId":"(\w{11})"')
    
matches = re.findall(pattern, html)
print(matches)
for i in range(3):
    print(matches[i])
```

Output is:

```
>python .\vidIDs.py
['jNQXAC9IVRw', 'jNQXACffRwl', 'jNQXAC9ffsw']
jNQXAC9IVRw
jNQXACffRwl
jNQXAC9ffsw
```